# Setting unknown property: yii\log\Logger::targets

Tags: yii, yii2

After Installed the Yii in my system when I try to run it getting this error.

*Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: yii\log\Logger::targets*

Comment: Looks like your log settings is wrong. Add your config (or at least its part that sets logging) to the question.

Comment: Just follow the instruction https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging#log-targets

Answer (score 1):

Here is some of the documentation I created while implementing logging in Yii, it might be of your help:

========================= Configure xampp to send the emails from localhost code ==========================================

Changes for C:\xampp\php\php.ini file:

search for [mail function]:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=localhost to SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from=me@example.com to sendmail_from=your email address
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
mail.log = syslog
```

Changes for C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini:

search for [sendmail]:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=same as "sendmail_from" in php.ini file
auth_password=generated password for the email account
force_sender= same as "auth_username" in this file
```

================================================ Restart Xampp Server =====================================================

=================================================== Add table in DB =======================================================
drop table if exists "log";

```
create table "log"
(
   "id"          number(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   "level"       integer,
   "category"    varchar(255),
   "log_time"    number,
   "prefix"      text,
   "message"     text,
   key "idx_log_level" ("level"),
   key "idx_log_category" ("category")
);
```

============================================ Configuration in Yii2 project ================================================

1. add in "components" array in app\config\console.php and app\config\web.php both files:

   ```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'your email address (for testing on localhost use same as in ini files)',
            'password' => 'generated password',
            'port' => 587,
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ], //end of mailer
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                'mailer' => 'mailer',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                //'categories' => ['yii\db\*'],
                'message' => [
                   'from' => ['your email address(for testing on localhost use same as in ini files)'],
                   'to' => ['receiptent email address'],
                ],
            ],
        ], // end of targets
        'flushInterval' => 1,
    ], //end of logs
   ```

//------------------------ web.php (log configuration setup) -------------------------//

//categories name would be later assgined to messages:

```
Yii::info($message, 'userNotification');
```